# Good 3D Math Theory Books

Tags: 3d, books, mathematics

I've been developing a modification for the Source engine for well over a year, but am now facing some troubles with the weapons, gamemovement (player physics) and player feedback from explosives.

This is all because of my weakness in mathematics!!!

What books, tutorials or any  other various texts could you recommend (that have helped you).

Comment: Since there is not really the "one true answer" for this, you might want to consider marking this a community wiki post.

Comment: When you ask users to create a list of answers, the question should be marked community wiki. I converted this question.

Comment: Any 3D graphics development requires a decent understanding of linear algebra. [Vector math tutorial for 3D Computer Graphics](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/vectorlessons/vectorindex.html) is by far the best resource for learning vectors and matrices. It is also interactive that each section has a test question to verify and seal the understanding of that topic.

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same issue some time ago and found those two books which have really good reviews:

- [3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556229119)
- [Essential Mathematics for Games and Interactive Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123742978)

The first one seems to be easier to understand for math dummies like myself. I already bought that one, alas I didn't have the time to read it up till now.

Comment: I have both these books at home, and they are both excellent.

Answer (score 5):

You're in luck! I just discovered some Linear Algebra tutorials on Wolfire's blog that I felt were really good. The guy writing the tutorials, David, has such a killer way to explain the stuff. It's extremely handy for those that are weak at math since it is showing more practical application than theory (which is what someone weak could use)

- [Part 1](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/) - Vectors addition, subtraction, scalar-vector multiplication
- [Part 2](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-2/) - Vectors length, distance, normalization, dot product, cross product
- [Part 3](http://blog.wolfire.com/2010/07/Linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-3) - Basis vectors, matrices, 3d matricies

Be sure to add this to your RSS reader. He is continually writing new posts. Don't forget to **read the comments**!

Comment: The urls are case-sensitive. Check your links.
And the ending slash in the url is required.

Comment: That was odd. *Should* work now.

Comment: Now "Part 2" and "Part 3" both links to part two.. :D

Comment: Darn capital L's and slashes. I shall prevail!

Answer (score 3):

I've found "Mathematics for 3D Game Programming and Computer Graphics" to be an excellent resource.  [http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Programming-Computer-Graphics-Development/dp/1584502770/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1279832969&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584502770)

Answer (score 2):

Another good resource in addition to the books listed here is [this Linear Algebra](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2005/) course at MIT Open CourseWare.

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to pick up "Tricks of the 3D Game Programming Gurus" (volume II). It seems really good on the 3d theory side and keeps everything simple from what I saw. I tried to pick up Direct3D/OpenGL alone but I'm like you - I had no idea.

Comment: I used these books when I was first learning but I feel more recently they did me a disservice by not focusing on good structure or concepts.