# Math for Game Developers

Tags: mathematics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What math should all game programmers know?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2029/what-math-should-all-game-programmers-know)

How many need know(learn) Math for Game Developer? for 2D and 3D games?
And where best learn Math for game development? in Wikipedia or maybe Books?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Primer-Graphics-Development-Wordware-Library/dp/1556229119/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1307031898&sr=8-2

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Game-Developers-Development/dp/159200038X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1307031898&sr=8-1

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend Daniel Kodicek's [Mathematics & Physics for Programmers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1435457331). Great sample code and detailed, illustrated explanations of everything.

---

[Google books page for 1st edition](http://books.google.com/books?id=8qBYYWbpLMUC&lpg=PP1&dq=Mathematics%20and%20Physics%20for%20Programmers&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Table of contents to give an idea of topics covered:

- Part I  General Techniques

  - Numbers
  - Arithmetic
  - Algebra
  - Trigonometry and Pythagoras
  - Vectors
  - Calculus
- Part II  Ballistics and Collisions

  - Acceleration, Mass, and Energy
  - Detecting Collisions Between Simple Shapes
  - Resolving Collisions
  - Detecting Collisions Between Complex Shapes
  - A Simple Pool Game
- Part III  More Complex Motion

  - Force and Newton's Laws
  - Angular Motion
  - Friction
  - Strings, Pulleys, and Conveyor Belts
  - Oscillations
- Part IV  3D Mathematics

  - 3D Geometry
  - Transforms
  - Collision Detection in Three Dimensions
  - Lighting and Textures
  - Modeling Techniques
- Part V  Game Algorithms

  - Speeding Things Up
  - Tile-Based Games
  - Mazes
  - Game Theory and AI
  - Search Techniques

---

Comment: `number_of_upvotes = quality_of_question * number_of_bullet_points * mystery_factor`