# How to get pixel coordinates between 0,1 from SV_POSITION

Tags: directx, shaders, hlsl

I am new to HLSL and Directx. I was trying to write a simple gradient Shader by modifying one of Microsoft samples.

1.I can not understand why SV_POSITION is float4? If it is pixel coordinates shouldn't it have only x and y ? What are the 4 parts? I think SV_POSITION is not between 0,1 and the maximum val is bufferWidth,bufferHeight ... then how can I get the position between 0,1?

1. The first code does not work because distance between float2 and float4 is impossible. While the second one works I get a warning. How can I avoid the warning message because I believe something is wrong!

Fist code (Of course it should not work):

```
float4 VS( float4 Pos : POSITION ) : SV_POSITION
{

    return Pos;
}

float4 PS(   float4 Pos : SV_POSITION) : SV_Target
{
    float distfromcenter=distance(float2(0.5f, 0.5f), Pos);
    float4 rColor = lerp(float4(0,0,0,1),float4(1,1,1,1), saturate(distfromcenter));
    return rColor;
}
```

The second one :

```
float4 VS( float4 Pos : POSITION ) : SV_POSITION
{

    return Pos;
}


float4 PS(   float2 Pos : TEXTCOORD  ) : SV_Target
{
    float distfromcenter=distance(float2(0.5f, 0.5f), Pos);
    float4 rColor = lerp(float4(0,0,0,1),float4(1,1,1,1), saturate(distfromcenter));
    return rColor;
}
```

Why do I get this warning ? How can I compile this Shader using SV_POSITION to avoid the warning message ?

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::Draw: Vertex Shader - Pixel Shader linkage error: Signatures between stages are incompatible. The input stage requires Semantic/Index (TEXTCOORD,0) as input, but it is not provided by the output stage. [ EXECUTION ERROR #342: DEVICE_SHADER_LINKAGE_SEMANTICNAME_NOT_FOUND]
```

Comment: It is an array/structure of 4 elements as an optimization. It is the same as why some APIs represent vectors as arrays of 4 floats even if the last element is not used for anything. Maybe somebody can post a link to a good explanation of why. I could not find one in my bookmarks.

Comment: BTW, of course the second one doesn't work because the pixel shader expects an input called `TEXTCOORD` and the vertex shader does not provide that (which is exactly what the warning is telling you).  But that has nothing to do with `SV_POSITION`.

Comment: @HatoruHansou: The GPU only works with registers of 4-component vectors.  "Libraries" use four components because the fourth component _is_ used for something: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17987/what-does-the-graphics-card-do-with-the-fourth-element-of-a-vector-as-the-final

Comment: @Nathan Reed
So in order to avoid the warning I must extract x,y position from SV_POSITION but the problem is that the values in SV_POSITION are not in [0,1] ! They are [0, bufferWidth] x [0, bufferHeight] range ! How can I map that into [0f,1f] ?

Comment: @user999792 Uhh...divide by bufferWidth and bufferHeight.

Comment: @ Nathan Reed I knew that :D but how? I searched but I could not find  a way to access bufferWidth directly inside the shader ! Should I send it using cbuffer ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new too in directx and not very good in english so i havent understand your question at all but...

Try to change the pixel shader like this:

```
float4 PS(float4 Pos:SV_POSITION):SV_Target //pos contain x,y,z,w but you only need x,y
{                             //remember PS is called for each pixel and so it must now the pixel-screen position
pixelPosX=Pos[0]; pixelPosY=Pos[1];//theese are the pixel coordinates in the window start from top-left corner and are integer ones(ex. 100-200, 0-0, window_width, window_height)
...
}
```

If the backbuffer width_height are different from window ones, i dont know if the max Pos[0] value( and Pos[1] too) is the window width or the bck buffer one.

Hope that it works.

Look the comment.

```
#define MAX_X 640
#define MAX_Y 400
Vertex shader....

float4 PS(float4 Pos:SV_POSITION):SV_TARGET
{
 int x=Pos[0]/MAX_X;
 .....
}
```

Comment: This wont work ! The SV_POSITION values are between Width and height not [0,1] while the code is intended to work with pixel position between [0,1]

Comment: You can obtin pixel position between [0,1] just with pos.x/max_x and pos.y/max_y. Es. pos.x=120; max_x=640; pos.x in float= 120/640=0.19;

Comment: I knew ... But max_x should be sent to shader with cbuffer ?

Comment: Yes, or define in it if the buffer's height-width is constant