# How to get depth of vertex in 0 - 1 range

Tags: directx, depth

I want to get the depth of vertex in 0 to 1 range(like it done in the shader) and I do it like this

```
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&vertex, &vertex, &wvp);

depth = vertex.z;
```

It works(sometimes wrong) but when I write This

```
    if (depth > 1.0f || depth < 0.0f)return false;
```

Sometimes it returns false. How can I get correct depth for vertex in 0 to 1 range??

I want to compare two vertexes and select the nearest

EDIT

```
    wvp = worldmatrix*viewmatrix*projectionmatrix;
```

It works wrong when I zoom in

Comment: Is there anything behind the camera?

Comment: No but .....`if(depth > 1.0f)` also returns false

Comment: Wait, what did you set the near clipping plane?

Comment: near is 0.1f and far is 1000.0f

Comment: Then in whít order do you multiply together the model, view and projection matrices

Comment: You know, it sould be like projection * view* model

Comment: For x and y I know we have to divide by w to get them in normalized device coordinates, but I can't recall whether z is special in that regard. (This is usually the kind of thing I solve by trying it both ways and seeing whether one fixes it, rather than a first-principles mathematical derivation...)

Comment: @Bálint The convention in D3DX is `v*M`. Do you have anything to back up your arbitrary swap of convention?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is the Z coordinate normalized in GLSL?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/66110/when-is-the-z-coordinate-normalized-in-glsl)

Comment: If you want to compare two vertices and select the nearest, then you'll find it much easier (and faster) to just compare squared distance of each from the camera.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the normalization step, which requires a **W component**.

Hence, you should be calling [D3DXVec4Transform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d9/dx9-graphics-reference-d3dx-functions-math) and not D3DXVec3TransformCoord.

You need to feed this your vertex, with the last component (W) set to a 1.0 value.

The output vertex will have W set in the last component, and you need to divide by that:

```
v_in[3] = 1.0;

D3DXVec4Transform
(
    &v_out,
    &v_in,
    &wvp
);

v_out[0] = v_out[0] / v_out[3];
v_out[1] = v_out[1] / v_out[3];
v_out[2] = v_out[2] / v_out[3];
```

Now you can use `v_out[2]` as the depth value, but beware: **it ranges from -1 to 1**, and not from 0 to 1 as you assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication is not commutative. You need to do `projection * view * model`

Comment: No it also dont works

Comment: Ok, try out something: before multiplying the vertex with the mvp matrix, multiply it with the mv matrix, and orint out the z value.

Comment: I have already done like that