# Should I Include the W-component of a vector when calculating it's length or dot product?

Tags: c++, vector

The reason I'm asking this is because I saw an implementation which did it that way but I don't quiet understand it. I mean, usually I want to get the distance between two points in 3d space and if W is something other than 0 the result is not correct. The same when calculating lighting using the dot product.

```
float Vector::Length() const{
    return sqrtf(X * X + Y * Y + Z * Z + W * W);    //W necessary?
}

float Vector::Dot(const Vector& other) const{
    return X * other.X + Y * other.Y + Z * other.Z + W * other.W;
}
```

Edit: There are suggestions that my question is a duplicate of already existing ones. But the questions referred to are about whether you need the W component at all and for what. I know what I need it for, I'm just not sure about it's role in the operations I specified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need the 'w' component in my Vector class?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/do-i-need-the-w-component-in-my-vector-class)

Comment: Or even [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17987/what-does-the-graphics-card-do-with-the-fourth-element-of-a-vector-as-the-final)...

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I don't think so. As you can read in my edit above, these questions are not the same as mine...

Comment: All right! I'll leave the link there just as a reference.

Comment: @aslg I think you have enough content there to make an answer :)

Comment: @aslg I agree with Alexandre. Your answer is clear and understandable. It makes much more sense that way, thank you :)

Comment: Well, an answer it is ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason you need to extend a vector to 4 dimensions (homogeneous coordinates, not 4-Dimensional space) is so that you can apply transforms or matrices (model, etc) to it. Unless you're explicitly making a game in a 4-Dimensional space you don't need to include the `w` component in the calculations you mentioned.

Indeed, as you noted, using a w different than 0 will of course yield wrong results for your typical 3D calculations.

Comment: I'd like to add that various transformations work out nicely if you represent points as coordinates with W = 1 and vectors (more accurately, "directions") as coordinates with W = 0.  For example, a point will be affected under translation, but a direction will not be.