# How do I convert sin, cos and tan into an int in Java?

Tags: java, mathematics

How would you be able to change `Math.sin`, `Math.cos` and `Math.tan` into an `int`?
This is because I heard that it is useful to have those Math resources in movement, gravity, etc. in gaming.
Also, as a little inside question, does anyone know if there is a method where you can square or cube a number instead of doing:
(Pseudo Example)
`9 * 9 * 9` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert any `float` or `double` to an `int` with a cast. For example:

```
int integerResult = (int)Math.sin(variable);
```

However, this really does not make sense. Since the result of `Math.sin()` will always be from -1 to 1, this cast will always make the result 0 or -1 or 1. From the sound of your question you're not very sure about how to use these. I would strongly recommend you brush up on your math skills before attempting anything too complicated with your programming. You can, of course, use these in floating point format instead of as an integer.

Your second question. `9 * 9 * 9` is equivalent to 9 cubed. You could make your own method for the clearest intent:

```
int cube(int input) {
    //return the input cubed
    return input*input*input;
}
```

Or use the built in function `Math.pow()` like so:

```
float nineCubed = Math.pow(9,3);
```

You can see check the [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) to see what functions Java has built in for math.

Finally, you can check out some of these math resources:

[What math should all game programmers know?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2029/what-math-should-all-game-programmers-know)

[Linear algebra for game developers part 1](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/)

Comment: The result of Math.sin() will be from -1 to 1. I would recommend looking at Math.pow(), which handles squaring, cubing and so forth. For example Math.pow(9,3) = 9*9*9.

Comment: @TaylorGolden No problem. If this answer was helpful to you, you can accept it as your answer. And welcome to GDSE!