# Learning math from the basic to become a game programmer

Tags: mathematics

Hi i want to become a game developer. Im currently doing some web programming. I want to learn
game programming. Im not good in math thats why i decided to learn from basic math to be sure i will not missed
some important concepts. Do you have some advice if my way of learning is ok. thanks.

Comment: My usual answer to this question is find something you want to do, and then learn the math to solve that problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have recommended earlier editions of the following book, and I imagine the current edition is equally good:

[http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Programming-Computer-Graphics-Edition/dp/1435458869](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1435458869)

After digging into that, my suggestion is to just practice: make some games.  When you run into specific problems, find the answer to them.

You can spend an entire lifetime learning the "foundations" of a craft without ever learning how to actually do perform that craft.  You'll only actually learn it by doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked [what-math-should-all-game-programmers-know?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2029/what-math-should-all-game-programmers-know?rq=1)

If you want to get into 3D then you will need to understand vector operations such as dot-product and cross-product. You will also need to understand matrix basis representation and representations such as the world-matrix. The easiest way is to follow a tutorial for some "My first 3D game" and try to understand the math as you go along.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting with basic addition(+) and subtraction(-) followed by multiplication(*) and then division(/) and fractions. If you can get to the point of working with three digits(804/268, for example) then that would be best before you continue.

After that you should start with algebra (A+B=C). When programming games (or programming in general) you will be using a lot of algebra.

I would say that only after this point should you start to play with actual code. [Math.com](http://www.math.com/) is a great FREE place to learn all you need. Good luck :)