# How is math connected to video games?

Tags: mathematics

I have to do a project for my math class in which I choose a topic and connect concepts we learned to it. I chose video games, and I was hoping someone could help me. Possible concepts: Quadratics, statistics, probability, vectors, trigonometry, etc. Or, if this is a terrible topic to write a minimum of 6 pages on, please tell me. P.S. I know absolutely nothing about code, programming, any of that.

Comment: The math is implemented in the code and programming. It's a great topic for a math paper. Check out this post to get some leads for your paper: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2029/what-math-should-all-game-programmers-know

Comment: Trig is sooo relevant to 2D games. Like, you know how in math class you calculate the hypotenuse of a right triangle? Getting the distance between objects is literally that.

Comment: @jhocking That's not trigonometry, that' simply the Pythagorean theorem. Calculating the angle of the triangle with atan is probably closer

Comment: Also, quadratic equations can be used to calculate where a projectile will land _before_ it landed, so that math can be used in AI.