# How do I find a point on a line?

Tags: mathematics, vector

I have two points (A, B) and the length of d. How can I find point C?

[image: example]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Compute a vector `V` from `A` to `B`, and normalize it.

```
V = (B - A) / |B - A|
```

Since the vector is normalized, it will have a length of one, and it will indicate the direction of `B` relative to `A`. If you then scale the vector by `d` you will have the displacement from `A` to `C`

```
V' = d * V
```

which you can simply add to `A` to yield `C`:

```
C = V' + A
```

Comment: btw: could anyone recommend me a book where I can learn about stuff like that? :)

Comment: 3D Math primer is a good one: http://www.amazon.com/Primer-Graphics-Development-Wordware-Library/dp/1556229119.

Comment: Didn't read this one, but I've been told that is also pretty good http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Programming-Computer-Graphics-Second/dp/1584502770/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1318320256&sr=1-5

Comment: See this question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/good-3d-math-theory-books

Comment: btw this is the last couple steps in ray intersection algorithms: you figure out how far along the ray the intersection point is, and then you get the coordinates of the point http://geomalgorithms.com/a05-_intersect-1.html#Plane-Intersections

Answer (score 1):

In case your d is a ratio instead of a length, e.g 0.5 puts it on equal distance from A and B, you can do the following and avoid a normalization:

```
C = A * (1 - ratio) + B * ratio
```